# Converting nested for loop to while loop python

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop, string-comparison

I know this may be a silly question but how do convert from `for loop` to `while loop` properly. If you are asking me why is because I wanted to know what does the structure of a while loop looks like if you have the `break`statement in the middle of a double `for loop`

This is my code so far:

```
genelist = []
integer = 0
for i in range(0, len(first_genome)):
    for j in range(0, len(second_genome)):
        integer = integer + 1
        if first_genome[i] == second_genome[j]:
            genelist.append(first_genome[i])
            break
return(genelist, integer)
```

The for loop has no error but whats bothering me that this code for the while loop:

```
    genelist = []
    integer = 0
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < len(first_genome):
        while i < len(second_genome):
            integer = integer + 1
            if first_genome[i] == second_genome[j]:
                genelist.append(first_genome[i])
                j = j + 1
                break
        i = i + 1
    return(genelist, integer)
```

is the same as:

```
    genelist = []
    integer = 0
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < len(first_genome):
        while j < len(second_genome):
            integer = integer + 1
            if first_genome[i] == second_genome[j]:
                genelist.append(first_genome[i])
                j = j + 1
                break
        i = i + 1
    return(genelist, integer)
```

How is this even possible?

Comment: It is not the same. Period.

Comment: I'm aware all 3 codes are not the same but when I run my program it produces the same output :/

Comment: But we don't know what is input and what output, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Codes are not the same.

In first while loop, you end in infinite loop as `i` is never incremented inside.
In second example, you have separated `i` and `j` codes.

What are you missing on second code is `j = 0` before starting inner `while` loop.

```
genelist = []
integer = 0
i = 0
j = 0
while i < len(first_genome):
    j = 0 #Added this
    while j < len(second_genome):
        integer = integer + 1
        if first_genome[i] == second_genome[j]:
            genelist.append(first_genome[i])
            j = j + 1
            break
    i = i + 1
return(genelist, integer)
```